# How to make 1 figure with 4 subfigures containing matrices?

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats, matrices, subcaption

like in the title, but below is an image I want to restore in my LaTeX document.
[image]

This is what I tried:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \newline
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    \newline
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Input}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        5 \\
        \hline
        8  \\
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Addition}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        8 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Multiplication}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Concatenation}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{xyz}
\label{fig:x}
\end{figure}
```

but it's not exactly what I want. I have alos a problem with centering 1st subfigure.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use? Can you make your code snippet be compilable?

Comment: Subfigure [b] aligns the captions.  Subfigure [t] will align the tabulars (baselines).  To do both you may need a tabular and \subcaption{...}.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the height of the tallest subfigure and the widths of the subcaptions. The syntax for `subcaption` is the same as for `minipage`, so you can specify a height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength{\subfigureht}
\newlength{\subfigurewd}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]

\settoheight{\subfigureht}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \endgraf\medskip
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \endgraf\vspace{0pt}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\addtolength{\subfigureht}{2\baselineskip}

\settowidth{\subfigurewd}{(m) Input}%
\begin{subfigure}[b][\subfigureht][s]{\subfigurewd}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \medskip

    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vfill
    \caption{Input}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \settowidth{\subfigurewd}{(m) Addition}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b][\subfigureht][s]{\subfigurewd}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        5 \\
        \hline
        8  \\
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vfill
    \caption{Addition}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \settowidth{\subfigurewd}{(m) Multiplication}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b][\subfigureht][s]{\subfigurewd}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        8 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vfill
    \caption{Multiplication}
 \end{subfigure}\hfill
 \settowidth{\subfigurewd}{(m) Concatenation}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b][\subfigureht][s]{\subfigurewd}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vfill
    \caption{Concatenation}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{xyz}
\label{fig:x}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. The explanation of the subfigures is done in the caption of the main figure. (and replaced the `\newline`s)

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

 \captionsetup{labelformat= empty, textfont=small} 
 \captionsetup[sub]{textfont=small} 

\usepackage{showframe}% only to show margins

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{figure}[h!] 
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
            \centering  \bfseries
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}
            \hline
            3 \\
            \hline
            1  \\
            \hline
            4 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}\\
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}
            \hline
            2 \\
            \hline
            7  \\
            \hline
            2 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering  \bfseries
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}
            \hline
            5 \\
            \hline
            8  \\
            \hline
            6 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering  \bfseries
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}
            \hline
            6 \\
            \hline
            7  \\
            \hline
            8 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
        \centering  \bfseries
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}
            \hline
            3 \\
            \hline
            1  \\
            \hline
            4 \\
            \hline
            2 \\
            \hline
            7  \\
            \hline
            2 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}  
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{(a) input \, (b) `+' addition \,  (c) `\times' multiplication \, (d) `\oplus' concatenation}
    \label{fig:x}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you want to add the symbols to the captions use, for example,    `\caption{\times}` in the subfigures.

[image: f]

Answer (score 0):

This uses tabularx to align the tabulars and subcaptions separately.  Captions begin and end with `\par`, so you need some sort of paragraph column type, and this also spaces them evenly (rather than based on the caption width).

Only the first tabular **needs** to be put into a savebox.  Also, varwidth does not play well with `\newline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\sbox0{\begin{varwidth}[c]{\linewidth}% special case
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vskip 0.5cm
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{varwidth}}%
%
\sbox1{\begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        5 \\
        \hline
        8  \\
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
%
\sbox2{\begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        8 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
%
\sbox3{\begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
% now format the whole thing
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CCCC}
    \usebox0 &
    \usebox1 &
    \usebox2 &
    \usebox3 \\
    \subcaption{Input} & \subcaption{Addition} & \subcaption{Multiplication} & \subcaption{Concatenation}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{xyz}
\label{fig:x}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version uses `\raisebox` to make LaTeX think all of the images are the same size (`\ht0` and `\dp0`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\sbox0{\begin{varwidth}[c]{\linewidth}% special case
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vskip 0.5cm
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{varwidth}}%
%
\sbox1{\begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        5 \\
        \hline
        8  \\
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
%
\sbox2{\begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        6 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        8 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
%
\sbox3{\begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline
        3 \\
        \hline
        1  \\
        \hline
        4 \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
        7  \\
        \hline
        2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
% now format the whole thing
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \usebox0
    \caption{Input}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \raisebox{0pt}[\ht0][\dp0]{\usebox1}
    \caption{Addition}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \raisebox{0pt}[\ht0][\dp0]{\usebox2}
    \caption{Multiplication}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \centering
    \raisebox{0pt}[\ht0][\dp0]{\usebox3}
    \caption{Concatenation}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{xyz}
\label{fig:x}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```